# Some users cannot accept the invitation from Azure AD (guest users)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Using the azure portal and the azure active directory I am sending out invitations to Guest Users. 90% of the time this works great - however there are some users where they cannot get logged in for the first time.

What sort of things should be analyzed?

Does their local AD (or possibly lack of) have anything to do with it?
Does their organization allowing users to receive mail with multiple email addresses have anything to do with it?

This has been a tough problem to solve as these are external users and it can be quite difficult to extract good information from them when attempting to diagnose the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean when you say users cannot get logged in for the first time? Are they seeing errors?

Comment: That's sort of the hard part about this. Since these are all external users spread out across the US it is hard getting good info from them.  Some cases they simply see something like "an error has occurred" - or even sometimes it tells them their user ID doesn't exist (it does) and needs to be added to the directory (and it already has).

Then sometimes, users that have already been able to log in for some time will suddenly get "incorrect username or password" - even though I truly think neither is the case. Even worse, Azure tells me "can't reset user's password" when I try to reset it.

Comment: Just a thought, have you considered using Azure B2C rather than inviting people as guests?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue that could be related.  It has to do with users that have both "work" and "personal" accounts that use the same email address.  When I invite them to my Azure directory, they are forced to sign in with their work account.  They do not get the option to sign in with their personal account.

Comment: @Micah_MSFT  can you explain that more plz? is there a cost to B2C? Are you saying guest users wont work? also, is B2B the same as guest users?